# How can we use flags in command line to run a ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want  to run a ruby file as `ruby sample.rb --flag[yes/no]=yes`

Then in **sample.rb** I need to get the flag value(yes) and do some operation.

Is this possible? If it is give me the solution.

Comment: Is `flag` the only option being passed to sample.rb?

Comment: No. It can be anything. But I want to access the given value (I mean yes/no) in sample.rb file and do some operations

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read command-line-arguments
you can access them in ARGV in the ruby program

For one argument, use

```
flag = ARGV[0]
```

For many, ARGV is an array

```
ARGV.each do |a|
  # process arguments like so
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Its Ok. I know it. What i want is I need to run command as "ruby sample.rb --xxx(yes/no)=yes. I need to get this "yes" in the ruby file and perform some operation

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`optparse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

Comment: Thanks. But I'm very new to ruby. Can you give me a sample code for this. It should be very simple. Please give me the sample code